# When realmResults.asObservable is called?

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I'm implementing a chat client. 
Everytime user clicks `Send message` button - I perform a Realm insert of this message.

I have a service 'waiting' for this change to send this message via socket. 
Like this:

```
    Observable<RealmResults<RealmMessage>> observable = getUnsentMessages();

    subscribeUnsendMessages = observable
            ...
            .subscribe(message -> {
                launchMessageSending(message);
            });
```

and method for getting this observable looks like this:

```
public Observable<RealmResults<RealmMessage>> getUnsentMessages() {
    final Realm instance = getRealmInstance();

    return instance.where(RealmMessage.class)
            ...
            .findAllAsync()
                .asObservable()
                .filter(o -> ... )
            .doOnUnsubscribe(instance::close);
}
```

And here is the problem - there is a corner case, when I perform two operations roughly at the same time. 
The second one looks like this:

```
public boolean shouldTrack(@NonNull RealmChat chat) {

    getRealmInstance().executeTransactionAsync(realm ->{
        RealmTrackedState trackedStates = realm.where(RealmTrackedState.class).findFirst();
        trackedStates.getRealmChats().add(chat);
    });

    return true;
}
```

The above method is a tracking cache for remembering if I tracked given chat or not.
(This is a bit more complicated than this, bear with me).

This *PROBABLY* causes the observer to react on the second database change. 
Because these two operations happen almost at the same time - the second notification is still "valid" because there is an unsent message.

So, questions:
Am I right? 
If so - how should I handle this?
I don't really want to 'delay' the `shouldTrack();` method because I'm afraid that the same problem will occur in a different way. 
Maybe create a flag for this message being 'handled', so the second will be ignored - but this is a bit nasty I guess. The second 'send' shouldn't happen.

EDIT:
Here is my TrackedState object

```
public class RealmATrackedState extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id = 1;

    private RealmList<RealmChat> realmChats;
    private boolean isSomething;
}
```

Is updating such object (as posted above) causing RealmMessage table be notified?

Comment: `asObservable()` is called when the Observable is notified that there was a transaction which wrote into the Realm and modified that given table (or since 3.0, modified that table in such a way that that particular results has changed)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Could you please take a look at my edit - I've updated my realm lib to 3.0 and it didn't help. :/

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Is `RealmMessage` related with `RealmATrackedState` or `RealmChat`? So what you want is `shouldTrack()` happen after the `getUnsentMessages()`?

Comment: @beeender There are meany RealmMessages with a chatID field. There are many RealmChats. Some RealmChats references are stored within RealmTrackedState. 

What I want (wanted, because I've dropped the idea of keeping whole RealmObject reference) is to not bother RealmMessages or RealmChats when copying a reference, because it doesn't change anything (from a human perspective). However it's not the Realm way, and apparently this is unavoidable.